Очень медленно ищет по бд sqllite
Имею проблему медленного поиска по бд sqlite(использую DB browser для визуализации).
БД размером 120 гб и имеет около 150 миллионов строк.
Формат данных:firstname,lastname,middlename,,dob,address,CITY,ST,zip,,number
Нужен поиск по firstname,lastname,zip(их обычно несколько), чтобы при удачном поиске совпадении выдавало целиком строку.
SELECT *
FROM CA
WHERE field1 = 'FIRSTNAME' AND field2 = 'LASTNAME' AND field9 IN (14211, 14211, 14211, 14212, 14211, 14211, 14208, 14211, 14212, 14208, 14215, 14208, 14211, 14215, 14211, 14222, 89103, 14208, 21040, 14212, 14222, 14222, 14212, 14211);

Все стоит на пк локально, есть ли способы ускорения поиска по бд по моим параметрам? Сейчас строку ищет за 20 минут, что не есть окей.
озу 32 гб, i5 10400f

Сразу очевиднейший вопрос — индексы-то есть?

Индексы добавлял, сейчас удалил. С ними как будто бы еще хуже

База находится на HDD или SSD? Вообще говоря, 100Mbyte/sec не такая уж неожиданно низкая скорость чтения.

@avp, но читать весь файл базы на каждый поиск - это какая-то дичь ;)

@Qwertiy, а что еще можно сделать если индексов нет?

@avp, ну, добавить индекс? А даже если не добавлять, числовая колонка - это 4 байта на строку - читать только её, а остальные столбцы проверять только если оно подойдёт. Да даже если читать все столбцы из запроса - это всё равно не вся таблица. И вообще, у него что, единственная таблица в базе?

Сделать vacuum, создать индексы, собрать статистику

Нужно разобраться для начала - какие вообще виды поиска у вас возможны. Если всегда по полным значениям столбцов поиск, то имеет смысл физически отсортировать данные и применить двоичный поиск. Может и БД вообще не нужна тогда. Нужны подробности.

@Qwertiy, вы о том, как надо поступать ТС, а я о том, как работает программа (СУБД) с тем что есть. Вообще, если речь только об этих данных и запрос всегда такой, то надо просто разнести эти данные по многим (скажем 1000) файлам в нескольких (скажем 30) каталогах. Имя каталога -- первая буква LAST_NAME, имя файла в каталоге -- вторая. Естественно все файлы отсортированы по LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME. Далее (я надеюсь) очевидно

@avp, ты предлагаешь вместо БД использовать ФС? Это ещё большая дичь - транзакционность придётся делать руками. БД и сами умеют кластеризацию, только вроде в этом вопросе она не в тему, а нужен нормальный индекс. И нет, я не верю, что при поиске по умолчанию читаются не только колонки из запроса, но и остальные колонки таблицы, и уж точно не другие таблицы.

@Qwertiy, да, ФС. Скорее всего у ТС нет никаких других таблиц, а есть какой-то дамп на писишке.  Если же речь все же о СУБД с транзакционностью, то пераллельно для новых поступлений можно использовать и базу. Переодически выгружать оттуда данные, обновляя файлы. И очищать базу не забывать. Иначе с таким количеством данных не справиться. Но скорее всего ничего там такого нет, иначе был бы, скажем, postgress или mysql, а не sqlite

@avp, а разве sqlite не умеет транзакционность? Думаю, у него не только чтение, но и запись есть?

@Qwertiy, думаю умеет. Реальная проблема sqlite в том, что он работает с одним устройством, поэтому принципиально не может быть действительно быстрым. Большие и быстрые СУБД могут "размазывать" таблицы по параллельным девайсам (но для ТС с его домашним компом это не вариант)

@Qwertiy, и все же, поскольку в sqlite есть понятие первичного ключа, то не все потеряно и очевидно производительность можно подтянуть к уровню ФС с отсортированными файлами

Автор, ну что там, есть подвижки?
